# How to loop through a list and make a new dataframe for every dataframe in that list in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for min_date in sms_df.cycle_end_date.unique():
    max_date = datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(days=75)
    days = pd.date_range(datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),max_date,freq='d')
    event_date_df = pd.DataFrame(days.values).rename(columns={0:'event_date'}).drop_duplicates()
    event_date_df['cycle_end_date'] = min_date
    event_date_df['event_date'] = event_date_df['event_date'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    new_df = new_df.append(event_date_df.merge(sms_df[sms_df.cycle_end_date == min_date], on=['cycle_end_date','event_date'], how='left'))
```

I had written the following for loop for `sms_df`
I also now have 4 EXACT TYPES of dfs : `sms_df, upi_df, flash_df, email_df, ivr_df` which needs to go through the same set of operations.
How do I make a LOOP and store each "new_df" seprately for upi, flash, email etc. using Python?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
reminder_list = [sms_df, upi_df, flash_df, email_df, ivr_df]
for n,df in enumerate(reminder_list):
    for min_date in df.cycle_end_date.unique():
        max_date = datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(days=75)
        days = pd.date_range(datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),max_date,freq='d')
        event_date_df = pd.DataFrame(days.values).rename(columns={0:'event_date'}).drop_duplicates()
        event_date_df['cycle_end_date'] = min_date
        event_date_df['event_date'] = event_date_df['event_date'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        reminder_list[n] = df
        df = df.append(event_date_df.merge(df[df.cycle_end_date == min_date], on=['cycle_end_date','event_date'], how='left'))
```